# Ranorex-like test case structure

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, ranorex

[image]

Figure above showed a TestSuite/Plan in Ranorex.

[SETUP] represents launching .exe recording while [TEARDOWN] represents exiting .exe.

1. How can I imitate the test case plan structure using only Visual Studio coded ui.

   - Since it will be repetitive to launch and close my .exe in every test case. If possible I would like to set it only once.
2. Does a [TestMethod] in coded ui represents a test case?

Comment: What does the diagram in your question mean? Please explain how it should be interpreted. A method with the `[TestMethod]` attribute is a test case.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the same problem and resolved it by first making an assumption.

A Microsoft *TestMethod* is not corresponding to a Ranorex *Test Case*, it is a Ranorex *Run Configuration* (as defined in the test suite).

A *Run Configuration* comes with configuration.  As you may already know, on the command line, it is possible to execute a Ranorex *Test Case* or a Ranorex *Run Configuration*, but it is better/easier to execute a *Run Configuration* since it comes with context (and also most development can be done by non-programmer from within Ranorex!).

In the end, what we did is use *TestMethod* to call Run Configuration(s).

The following Ranorex *How To* article describes how to do this:
http://www.ranorex.com/news/article/howto-test-automation-with-tfs-and-ranorex.html

If this method does not suit your setup, you can probably invoke Ranorex *Test Cases* directly in test method (and do whatever sequence you wish to replicate as shown in your test suite), but that would be more complicated and involve more maintenance IMHO (which must be done by programmers).

Hope this helps!

Hugo

Comment: Hi, actually I'm not doing an integration with Ranorex. I'm just evaluating VS coded ui. I want to know if whatever features available in Ranorex can be done in VS and how if possible.

Comment: Like I always answer to testers in our test automation team: Anything can be done!  It's just time and money that limit us. In other words, using code, you can quite easily reproduce what is represented in the test suite screenshot you provided, but that would require programming skills...  This is the reason we chose to develop our test automation using Ranorex (no or basic programming skills required).

Answer (score 0):

You're right about `[TestMethod]` representing a test case.

To Imitate the [Setup] and [TearDown] behavior of Ranorex, instead of using the `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` attributes, you should use the `[ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]` attributes (or `[AssemblyInitialize]` and `[AssemblyCleanp]` if you want them to run once for all *classes* in the project).

Note that these methods must be `static`, and the initialize ones should accept a `TestContext` parameter.